# Issue: Could not load OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, openssl, vps

On server after installing rvm, while doing `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following errors. So I am not able to install other requirements in ubuntu 12.04

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.2/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.2/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.2/net/https.rb:92:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/god-0.13.3/lib/god/conditions/http_response_code.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/god-0.13.3/lib/god.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/god-0.13.3/lib/god/cli/run.rb:89:in `block in run_daemonized'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/god-0.13.3/lib/god/cli/run.rb:87:in `fork'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/god-0.13.3/lib/god/cli/run.rb:87:in `run_daemonized'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/god-0.13.3/lib/god/cli/run.rb:21:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/god-0.13.3/lib/god/cli/run.rb:8:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/god-0.13.3/bin/god:124:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/god-0.13.3/bin/god:124:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/god:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/god:19:in `<main>'
    Failed to load /home/shivraj/.gemrc

    Could not load OpenSSL.
    You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile from       'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with
    OpenSSL using RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try once before everything

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Comment: thnx Sabyasachi, but i uninstalled all and reinstall, it worked.

Comment: @user2606967 then previously it might not have been installed properly.